# Gitolite Error: gitolite-admin not a repo

Tags: linux, git, gitolite

**Quick Note**: Before anyone points it out, I did originally post this on Server Fault, but after doing so I realized this site may be more appropriate. Sorry for the "double post".

I had installed gitolite about 6 months ago and all of a sudden I started getting this error:

```
fatal: 'gitolite-admin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have read a lot of other topics on this and done everything they suggested from removing the auth keys and adding a config file in ~/.ssh. Mine is below:

```
host myhost
   user git
   hostname myhost
   port 22
   identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

host mygit
   user git
   hostname myhost
   port 22
   identityfile ~/.ssh/obto
```

Sadly, though, I'm still getting the fatal error. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: All of a sudden? No updates on the machine or whatever?

Comment: I believe it's because an authorized key was made for the same key I use on gitolite, or something similar. Thing is, I've already removed said authorized key as suggested in other posts so I'm a bit clueless what to do next.

Comment: First, take the error literally.  Does gitolite-admin on your local machine look and act like a repository?  Or did you accidentally delete the .git directory?  Can you rename it and then re-clone it? If so, does the new clone work?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by doing what you just said: I create a file called **config** in my client machine:

vim ~/.ssh/config

```
Host 192.168.0.14
     user git
     hostname 192.168.0.14
     port 22
     identityfile ~/.ssh/userX
```

The **userX** file is your public file (userX.pub). Then I cloned the **gitolite-admin** repository in my client machine by doing:

```
**git clone 192.168.0.14:gitolite-admin**

Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'... Enter passphrase for key
'/home/userX':
```

Now you should enter the password of your key. And that's it. I hope this helps.

Regards.